# Opportunity Owner Name

Tags: apex, query

How can query Opportunity Owner Name?

I tried:

```
public List<Opportunity> opportunity{get;set;}

opportunity = [SELECT Name,OwnerId
                       FROM Opportunity
                       ];
```

But I only need first and last name.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the below query. `Ownerid` will return only the id of the owner. You have to use `Owner.name` as below.

```
SELECT id ,name,owner.Name,ownerid from opportunity
```

Comment: It worked, but why gave out the same name many times in a row, how to make it show only once?

Comment: Do you want that for single opportunity? If that is the scenario you have to use the where condition in the query.

Comment: And what should be in where?

Comment: Can we know what exactly you are trying to do . Please edit the question and mention what exactly is required. Are you trying to use the standard controller?

Comment: I'm trying to create an invoice and I just need an Opportunity Owner Name. Just to have it shown and that's it.Yes I am using a standard controller

Comment: Can you try the below. `public Oppy(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    Opportunity opp = [SELECT id ,name,owner.Name,ownerid from opportunity WHERE Id = :controller.getId()];
}`

Comment: Oh, please forgive me, no, I'm not using a standard controller. Maybe  can enter an account id or something in where?